# play video inside frame iOS (and center it)

Tags: objective-c, ios

I don't want to play a video in fullscreen, is it possible to play a video inside a view?

Here is my code. It does create a frame and plays the video inside it. The problem is that I don't know how to center on screen the frame (it appears on the right side of the screen)

[Screenshot](http://s9.postimage.org/eou3rrf0f/Captura_de_pantalla_2012_12_28_a_la_s_10_13_42.png)

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[bundle pathForResource:@"movie" ofType:@"mov"]];

_moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                       selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                           name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                         object:_moviePlayer];

_moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;
_moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(184, 200, 400, 300);
[self.view addSubview:_moviePlayer.view];
_moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace a line with given below will fix your issue.

```
_moviePlayer.view.center = self.view.center;
```